# Python For loop stops working in the middle

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, while-loop

The variables in the list work fine with the code: pyautogui.typewrite(i) and stop working on random halfway through the list.

What enhancements could be made in the following, and how could I make it get to the end of the file at all costs?

Could it have something to do with other statements other than the for loop, or shall I come up with a better approach to fetching the list from the text file?

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
results = []
    with open('H:\RetiredDevices.txt') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            results.append(line)


while True:

    for i in results:
        pyautogui.click(PressEnter1)
        pyautogui.click(PressEnter1)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click(PressEnter2)
        #pyautogui.click(PressEnter3)
        pyautogui.click(PressEnter4)
        pyautogui.typewrite(i)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(1)
        retired_devices.append(i)
        results.remove(i)


    if len(results) == 0:
        break
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `while` loop?

Comment: To break the for loop after finishing the list

Comment: Your `while` does exactly the opposite. A `for` loop can iterate through a list on its own. You don't need any additional control structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is causing you to skip some elements in your list: `results.remove(i)`

**Demo:**

```
res = [k for k in range(0,10)]

for i in res:
    print(i)
    res.remove(i)

>>>output
    0
    2
    4
    6
    8
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `results.remove(i)` in the loop itself. You generally don't want to add or remove things from a list you're iterating over while you're still iterating over it. Normally I would suggest adding all of the items to be removed to another list, then iterating over that list to remove them from the original list. Here it looks like you already are adding them to `retired_devices`, so I would iterate over `retired_devices` after the loops ends and `results.remove(i)` for every i in `retired_devices`. You also don't need the `while` loop, the `for` loop will end when it's done with all elements.